# Keep both background and menu bar fixed in position

Tags: html, css, background

I was trying to fix BOTH the menu bar and the background's positions.

So I add this code to the body to fix the background's position:

```
<body style ="width: 100%; background-image: url(images/bkgd3_1260_black.jpg); background-attachment:fixed; background-size: cover; background-position:center;>
    <div id="menu-bar"> xxxxx
    </div>
    <---other content--->
</body>
```

And I put a code under head tag for fixing the menu bar's position, i.e.:

```
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        #menu-bar {
            position: fixed;
            left: 0px;
            top: 0px;
            width: 1000px;
            height: 25px;
            z-index: 100;
            background-color: #040404;
            font-family: Calibri;
            font-size: 16px;
            font-style: normal;
            text-transform: none;
            text-decoration:none;
            color: rgb(231,231,231);
            line-height: normal;
            letter-spacing: normal;
            text-align: left;
            word-spacing: normal;
            display: table-row;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            border-bottom-width: thin;
            border-bottom-style: solid;
            border-left-style: none;
            border-right-style: none;
            border-top-style: none;
            border-bottom-color: rgb(204,255,38);
        }
    </style>
<head>
```

However, the result is: the background is fixed, but the menu bar is not. when I scroll down, the menu bar just disappear. I actually want it to stay at the very top.

any suggestions?

Comment: Seems to work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/ultranaut/scE78/ Is there more going on than you're letting on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the closing " in your body style declaration.